# How To Align Form Tags Properly?

Tags: html, forms, tags, alignment

I want to align the input and form elements to the right and have the label informatuion to the left, all while maintaining the label being vertically centered with each input it is aligned up to. I also need some space between each `<li>` tag per se.

You can view what I am talking and asking about here... http://jsfiddle.net/CCxwF/

Comment: I generally like to put the `<input>` inside the `<label>` and float the input inside the label.

Comment: +1 @Rikudo. This is allowed by the spec and it is much better than people wrapping forms in tags like `<p>`

Comment: Posted my working answer. Great question though, many developers seek the correct way of doing what you seek. +1'd and fav'd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this css instead:

```
label {display: block; margin: 5px 10px; float: left; width: 200px;}
input, select {float: left; width: 150px;}
ul li {clear: both;}
input.checkbox {width: inherit; margin: 5px 0 0 0;}
```

change the label closing tag for uncategorized to before the checkbox input and add class `checkbox` to checkbox

else if you want to keep the label around the checkbox you could use this style:

```
label {display: block; margin: 5px 10px; float: left; width: 200px; position: relative;}
input, select {float: left; width: 150px;}
ul li {clear: both;}
input.checkbox {width: inherit; margin: 5px 0 0 0;}
```

Comment: The `type="checkbox"` input doesn't look right, at least in Chrome, but this is very close.

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the `<ul>` entirely, setting `display: block` on the `<label>`s does the trick just fine.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2SjNX/)**

In this example, each `<label>` is set to be a `block` level element, and each `<input>` or `<select>` is set to float right inside of it. The black lines are for clarity only (only so you can see what are labels).

Comment: Having the control inside the label frees you from having to match them with for/id (I don't like `for` as it promotes `id`itis).

Comment: The text may also be placed inside a `span`, allowing more positioning flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like using definition lists (although this doesn't vertically align your `<label>`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/CCxwF/5/

You might also want to consider adding `id` attributes to your elements within your forms, and doing `label for="element-id"`

Comment: Actually no need for a list whatsoever, a form is not a list, nor a definition nor an (un)sorted list.

Comment: @Rikudo: At its simplest, a form is just a collection of inputs.  An unordered list or definition list makes perfect semantic sense for this, and that's why there's a very large number of professionals who design forms in this manner.